# CSS: set image height; aspect ratio; Gall-Peters projection

Tags: css, aspect-ratio

I have a Gall-Peters projection on my website.  I want to give the image 100% of available width while keeping the height correct so that countries do not get elongated. What is the right CSS to keep the aspect ratio?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply `width: 100%`. The height of an image should automatically be set to keep the original aspect ratio.